# How to make unit test with `asyncio.sleep()` contained code?

Tags: python

I have a problem to write asyncio.sleep contained unit tests. Do I wait actual sleep time...?

I used `freezegun` to mocking time.
This library is really helpful when I try to run tests with normal callables. but I cannot find answer to run tests which contains asyncio.sleep!

```py
async def too_many_sleep(delay):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    do_something()

def test_code():
    task = event_loop.create_task(too_many_sleep(10000))
    # I want test like `assert_called(do_something)` without realtime delays
```

What I want:

```py
def test_code():
    task = event_loop.create_task(too_many_sleep(10000))

    ...
    # trick the time
    with time_shift(sec=10000):
        assert task.done()
```

What I'm doing:

```py
def test_code():
    task = event_loop.create_task(too_many_sleep(10000))
    # run tests and I will see a sunrise
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `freezegun` doesn't patch affect `asyncio.sleep()`, because `freezegun` doesn't patch the [asyncio `loop.time()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.time).

There is an [existing issue in the `freezegun` project repository](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/issues/290) that asks how to deal with `asyncio.sleep()`, but it is still open with no proposed solution.

You could just mock `asyncio.sleep()` yourself:

```
from unittest import mock

class AsyncMock(mock.MagicMock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

with mock.patch('asyncio.sleep', new_callable=AsyncMock):
    task = event_loop.create_task(too_many_sleep(10000))
```

The above replaces `asyncio.sleep` with an `AsyncMock()` instance for the duration of the test, and `AsyncMock()`, when called, just does nothing.