# Speeding up wall clock with Python asyncio for testing

Tags: python, time, pytest, python-asyncio

I'd like to test some long-running Python asyncio code (using pytest). The code is slow to run because it sleeps a lot, waiting for various timeouts. Is there anything that lets you run asyncio code as if wall clock is running more quickly - so the test can be ran in reasonable time?

Of course Python *code* can't be magically made to run faster, rather I'd like to make the wall clock run e.g. 2x or 10x faster, so that `asyncio.sleep()` returns sooner. I would also need Python date and time functions to respect the resulting time (time.time() and datetime.datetime.today / datetime.date.today).

E.g. imagine the following code:

```py
async def slow_fn():
    result = []
    for ii in range(10):
        result.append((ii, datetime.datetime.now()))
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    return result
```

This clearly takes 10 hours when ran in real-time, but its output can easily be simulated over a very short time.

Some options I considered and I don't think they help:

- I could use something like faketime to *set* the time, but it's not clear to me that I can use it also to make time flow *faster*.
- It is not practical to [re]-write the code in such a manner that e.g. the sleep time is parametric, then use a shorter sleep interval in tests. For example, parts of the code wait for a particular *time*, not for a particular length of time. It is essential to the logic that e.g. something happens once per hour.
- There exists a really cool library Simpy: https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which simulates such events not in real time (so e.g. the sample code would evaluate immediately), except it doesn't work in real-time too. Whereas I want to write code using asyncio, then test it in short time in Python.

I wonder if there is some ground source of truth of time in Python, and whether than can be monkeypatched in a pytest test, so make it appear to run more quickly. And if so, would it mess up various Python internals? Or other suggestions for working around this issue are also welcome.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747998/how-to-make-unit-test-with-asyncio-sleep-contained-code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are covered by the well known "freezegun" Python library.

I myself had just used it to "freeze" all datetime methods at a given value - but checking the docs, it can also "speed-up" time and allow you to manually set timestamps between code interations -

https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

Answer (score 1):

I've found this is easier done by mocking the timeouts to be shorter, either by [mocking `asyncio.sleep()` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747998/how-to-make-unit-test-with-asyncio-sleep-contained-code) or naming the timeout value(s) somewhere else to override

```py
TIMES = {
    "timeout": 60**2,  # 1 hour in seconds
}

    ...
    await asyncio.sleep(TIMES["timeout"])
```

Don't rely on and save datetimes if possible, instead calculate their offsets directly for your purposes, writing a unit test if you depend on special deltas (regular case, what happens during daylight savings, NTP slew, etc.? which are much more important to handle and will break cases that naively speed up or slow down real time)